# Is there a possibility to disable Firefox getUserNameAndPasswordFields

Tags: javascript, firefox, password-manager

I have a website with a lot of HTML elements. The website is very slowly in Firefox at the first click to an input element, because the getUserNameAndPasswordFields in LoginManagerChild.jsm is called about 28.000 times is ~60s. (recorded with the Firefox runtime analysis). In Chrome the side loads very fast.

Is there a possibility to disable the getUserNameAndPasswordFields function?

Comment: I mean, individuals can on their own installations of Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/976192. Otherwise, there isn't from the web page. You can add `autocomplete="off"` to all of your `input` elements, but that function will still run...

Comment: thanks, autocomplete="off" brings me to the right way

Answer (score 0):

I have now removed all forms from the site, so no check will be performed. Previously all input fields was checked, also outside of the form.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).